# Find cliques of length k in a graph

Tags: python, networkx, clique-problem

I'm working with graphs of ~200 nodes and ~3500 edges. I need to find all cliques of this graph. Using networkx's `enumerate_all_cliques()` works fine with smaller graphs of up to 100 nodes, but runs out of memory for bigger ones.

> "This algorithm however, hopefully, does not run out of memory
>       since it only keeps candidate sublists in memory and
>       continuously removes exhausted sublists."[source code for enumerate_all_cliques()](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/_modules/networkx/algorithms/clique.html)

Is there maybe a way to return a generator of all cliques of length k, instead of all cliques, in order to save memory?

Comment: How big of a k are you thinking?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your priority is to save memory rather than getting all cliques. In that case the use of [networkx.find_cliques(G)](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html#networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques) is a satisfactory solution as you will get all maximal cliques (largest complete subgraph containing a given node) instead of all cliques.

I compared the number of lists (subgraphs) of both functions:

`G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(300,0.08)
print 'All:',len(list(nx.enumerate_all_cliques(G)))
print 'Maximal',len(list(nx.find_cliques(G)))`

> All: 6087
>
> Maximal 2522

And when the number of edges increases in the graph the difference in results gets wider.